# GA implementation for optimization of robotic manipulator link length

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am planning to use GA for optimization of link length of a robotic arm in MATLAB. In which I randomly generate link length population to be optimized, but some of these link length could be invalid as the robot may not be able to approach desired location with those link length, so the population will be reduced. Whats the approach for using GA for these kind of problems where some of the parameters generated have to be checked for feasibility before evaluating the fitness function?

Comment: See https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html or for background information: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com

Comment: Thanks Leander, can you please tell which category this problem falls under? e.g. constrained nonlinear optimization

Comment: I have no clue about robotics, but just from what I understand you have some function that you want to find the minimum of with the condition that the sum of all parameters is smaller than some value. If the function is nonlinear you could use `fmincon` (constrained *nonlinear* optimization), if it is linear you could use `linprog` (constrained *linear* optimization).